# Why isn’t a hypergeometric distribution actually called a *hyperbinomial* distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, terminology

An experiment is binomial if

- the experiment consists of a finite number of trials
- each trial results in one of two outcomes (i.e., success or failure)
- the probability of success is the **same** for every trial since the trials are **independent**

If a binomial experiment that consists of sampling *with* replacement is altered to consist of sampling *without* replacement, it becomes a hypergeometric experiment.

The notations I see most commonly are

$$X\sim\mathrm{B}(n,p) \iff \operatorname{P}(X=x)=\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^x$$
$$X\sim\text{hypergeometric} \iff \operatorname{P}(X=k)=\frac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

The word *geometric* evokes in me associations of scaling by a constant, like in a geometric sequence $\{a_nr^n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$. It seems to me that it would make more sense to call it a *hyperbinomial* distribution.

Why is this distribution named the way it is? In what way is a hypergeometric distribution related to a geometrical functions, series, sequences, etc.?